# CoC and Leadership CoC links in FAQ go to the same page

Tags: discussion, ubuntu-community, site-faq

In the second paragraph of the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq), two links (shown in bold) point to the same page:

> Please follow the **Ubuntu Code of Conduct**, **Ubuntu Leadership Code of Conduct**, and this FAQ when participating in this community.

That link is: http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/conduct

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): [Can we update the election page to reflect code of conduct changes?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5981/can-we-update-the-election-page-to-reflect-code-of-conduct-changes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You are correct, the FAQ should be changed.

[Our FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq) says:

> Please follow the [Ubuntu Code of Conduct](http://www.ubuntu.com/community/conduct), [Ubuntu Leadership Code
> of Conduct](http://www.ubuntu.com/community/leadership-conduct), and [this FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq#etiquette) when participating in this
> community.

The first link is http://www.ubuntu.com/community/conduct.
The second link is http://www.ubuntu.com/community/leadership-conduct.

That is correct. But:

- The [1st link](http://www.ubuntu.com/community/conduct) redirects me to http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/conduct.
- The [2nd link](http://www.ubuntu.com/community/leadership-conduct) **also** redirects me to http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/conduct!

At first I thought this was a bug in [ubuntu-website-content](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-website-content), but it turns out there is no bug there. Instead, they both redirect to the same page because **as of [CoC 2.0](https://launchpad.net/codeofconduct/2.0), there is [no separate Leadership Code of Conduct](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-news-team/2012-November/001684.html)** (that material is now covered in the code of conduct for everyone).

Therefore, we should change the FAQ. It should probably just say:

> Please follow the [Ubuntu Code of Conduct](http://www.ubuntu.com/community/conduct) and [this FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq#etiquette) when
> participating in this community.

<sub>As the CoC and Leadership CoC merge confused me and perhaps others, I made [this question on main](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250991/what-happened-to-the-leadership-code-of-conduct) about the change.</sub>

***This answer is changed heavily from earlier versions. [Check this out](https://meta.askubuntu.com/revisions/5978/2), to see what it used to look like.***