# Can we update the election page to reflect code of conduct changes?

Tags: discussion, election, ubuntu-community

The [introductory page about moderator elections](https://askubuntu.com/election/3?cb=1) still contains text about the *Ubuntu Leadership Code of Conduct*. As that was merged into the *Ubuntu Code of Conduct* the page needs updating. It might need other improvements too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be slightly more involved to fix than [the corresponding issue in the FAQ](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5975/22949). But only slightly.

I think plenty of people have only signed CoC 1.1. But [it was as of CoC 2.0 that the Leadership CoC was merged in](https://askubuntu.com/a/250992/22949).

Accessing https://launchpad.net/codeofconduct while not logged in to Launchpad reveals that CoC 1.1 is considered obsolete. So there should be no problem requiring people to sign CoC 2.0. However, while logged in, users (like me) who have signed CoC 1.1 and not yet 2.0 see:

> Congratulations, you have already [signed](https://launchpad.net/%7Edegeneracypressure/+codesofconduct) the Ubuntu Code of Conduct.

<sup>(Links point to the logged-in user's page; they don't all point to mine.)</sup>

And it does not mention anything about a need to sign CoC 2.0.

So:

- If we're going to require candidates to sign CoC 2.0, we'll have to make clear that they must do so even if they've signed any previous version.

  I recommend we do this. But I don't think we should disqualify nominees for not having signed it. Instead, they can simply be encouraged to sign it as soon as possible, and before the election phase. (Of course, if everyone signs it before self-nominating, that is best.)
- If we are not going to require this, we'll still have to change the election page, as right now the Leadership Code of Conduct link redirects to CoC 2.0. In this case we'd have to decide exactly what we'd want it to say.
- It would be good to deal with this soon, as the nomination phase of the election starts tomorrow, and it's always best for all formal qualifications for office to be clear from the get-go.

#### Update

The election page was updated (last week, actually, and I think in time for the start of the election--thanks to [jrg♦](https://askubuntu.com/users/6005/jrg) for the fix!). The new version says:

> signed the [Ubuntu Code of Conduct](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100275/how-do-i-sign-the-ubuntu-code-of-conduct), 2.0, and link to your Launchpad.net page showing you have signed.

Less time-sensitively, we should still update [the FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq#questions) and ask Stack Exchange to update their [terms of service](http://stackexchange.com/legal) (both of which refer and links to the CoC and Leadership CoC separately, where both links actually lead to the CoC 2.0).

*Related:* [CoC and Leadership CoC links in FAQ go to the same page](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5975/coc-and-leadership-coc-links-in-faq-go-to-the-same-page)

Comment: I suggest you guys come up with a specific change to the links / wording and then let me know about it. I have another change I need to make to that page anyway.